# Can I add a NOT NULL constraint to a CockroachDB column?

Tags: cockroachdb

I want to add `NOT NULL` to a column, but it looks like `ADD CONSTRAINT` doesn’t support it. How can I add the constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Cockroach does not currently allow adding these constraints to an existing table.

One workaround is to create a new table with the schema you want to use (including the `NOT NULL` constraint), and then migrate the data to the new table using `INSERT...SELECT`.

Here’s an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl2 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, col_a INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl2 SELECT * FROM tbl1;
```

This assumes that `tbl1` has the same number of columns with the same types and doesn’t have any *NULL* values in its version of `col_a`.

The downside of this is that it has to copy *all* the table data, so it is not ideal on large tables.

Another workaround would be to add a new column, with the `NOT NULL` constraint (which implies it would also require a `DEFAULT`), then use an `UPDATE` to set its value from the existing column, then rename the new column and drop the old one.